# Генератор документации из markdown файлов

Tags: документация, markdown

Есть ли какая-то тулза для генерации документации из markdown фалов ?
На вход передать n-е количество markdown файлов и получить на выходе готовый файл с документацией в `.md` формате?

Comment: Таких инструментов десятки. Возьмите тот, который написан на знакомом вам языке программирования. https://www.staticgen.com/

Comment: @NickVolynkin эти инструменты, как я понял, генерируют сайты, а мне нужно взять несколько маркдаун-файлов передать их генератору и получить готовый полноценный маркдоун файл, который я просто залью в бд и буду использовать как документацию

Comment: Тогда расскажите, пожалуйста, что этот генератор должен делать?

Comment: @NickVolynkin мне нужен генератор, который будет возвращать страницу склееную с файлов которые я ему передам, тоесть мне не подходит что бы файл ранился используя backend

Comment: а  эти генераторы на сколько я понял, используют

Comment: Это генераторы статических сайтов. Они берут маркдаун и из него делают сайт только из HTML, CSS, JS, без активного бэкенда. И этот сайт вы потом деплоите просто под nginx или на GitHub/GitLab Pages.

Comment: понял, спасибо)